# View lose cornerRadius with Animation of UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, core-animation

In the code, I have set:

```
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2;
```

And run it in animation block:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:imageView
                      duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    animations:nil
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        imageView.hidden = YES;
                    }];
```

But when running on iOS 8, the `imageView` is back to normal, means there is no `cornerRadius` for `imageView`.

Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: what _employeeImage here ?

Comment: Sorry, it supposed to be `imageView`. Thanks.

Comment: so is prob solved in you code too ?

Comment: see my ans mate ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to slash corners of `UIImage` not `UIImageView` using `CALayer` using below code.

```
// load image on imageView programmatically 
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];

// assign the changes reflected using method before load image to imageView
image = [self makeRoundedImage:image radius:_imageView.frame.size.width/2];
_imageView.image = image;
```

---

```
// method to create round image
-(UIImage *)makeRoundedImage:(UIImage *) image radius: (float) radius{

    CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    imageLayer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;

    imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
    imageLayer.cornerRadius = radius;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [imageLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return roundedImage;
}
```

Now you can apply animation simply.

Comment: yeah, this is what I solve this problem temporary, but what I need to understand why it happens? not another approach. But thanks a lot bro.

Comment: couldn't found permanent solution ?. I have written the **reason** in my ans `You need to slash corners of UIImage not UIImageView`.

Comment: according to your approach you are creating round corners of `imageView` but the `image` inside is still in own shape until you apply any changes so whenever you apply animation the image will rotate in 360 degree and the shape will remain until you create round corners of `image` .. this is not a another approach

Comment: I think it is not correct, Because this only happens on ios8, on ios9 it works fine. How do you think bro?

Comment: have you applied ? what iOS version you are using ?

Comment: `[UIView transitionWithView:_employeeImage
                          duration:1.0
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                        animations:nil
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            _employeeImage.hidden = YES;
                        }];`

Comment: I'm using ios 9, it's running fine.

Comment: so whats the prob brother why cant you accept and upvote :)

Comment: it's okay for me, but actually, you did not solve my problem. So i'm feel free to up vote but not accept. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122183/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-nghia-luong).